# Drop down menu - data validation - looking for source

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu

I have been wracking my brain and I’ve lost all will to work (yay!) I have a spreadsheet (wow!) with a drop-down menu and want to remove the drop down list – start new/fresh - however in the validation data tab there is no source to “clear all” and I cannot for the life of me find the main cell that’s picking up the list - but the list is there – just no link or there is one but it’s invisible.

I can’t even create a new column to create a new drop-down because for some reason it copies the same cells over into the new column automatically so I’m stuck with the same list without being able to change it.

Am I missing something?? I can’t see any hidden rows or columns.  I also have a drop-down menu where I don’t even know or can’t even see the list. The spreadsheet is not linked to any other worksheet either and it was created a while back by a person who no longer works here, so can't ask them.

Please don’t tell me I have to create a whole new spreadsheet – there is way too much data in there and it’s giving me a headache. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated and would save me from going grey prematurely.

I'm using Windows 10 pro and Excel 2016.

Comment: Have you tried selecting all the cells on the sheet and using "clear all" on the bottom left of the data validation box?

Comment: When you say Validation Data tab, are you talking about a worksheet tab at the bottom of the workbook, or the Data Validation button on the ribbon under the Data tab at the top of the Excel application?

Comment: The button on the ribbon under the Data tab is the one I am referring to, I have tried the "clear all" on the validation box but there is no source for it to clear, that's my problem so it won't allow me to do it.

Comment: Could it be a well disguised Active-X Control object?

Answer (score 0):

**Excel Method:**

Data - Data Tools - Data Validation - Settings tab - Clear All.

**VBA Method (One sheet):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear_Validation()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        .Cells.Validation.Delete
 
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**VBA Method (Loop sheets):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear_Validation()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        With ws
        
            .Cells.Validation.Delete
 
        End With
        
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```